# Set keymap on LiveCD

Tags: livecd, keymap

With VmWare Workstation 7.1 here, I'm having trouble with BackTrack 4 Live CD.

For some reason, the mouse won't right-click where it appears to be. This would be due to VmWare tools not being installed, but it's a live CD.

I decided to do everything via the terminal, but I have an Azerty keyboard. I need to load the keymap, but I don't know the correct name for it.

I know that I can use the command "loadkeys", but I don't know the argument needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on a Linux console, `loadkeys` is indeed the right command. The argument is the path to a keymap file from the current directory or from `/usr/share/keymaps`; if you don't include a directory component then `loadkeys` will also search subdirectories of `/usr/share/keymaps` recursively. Furthermore you can leave out `.map` or `.kmap` at the end and supported compression suffixes. For example (assuming BackTrack includes the same keymaps as Debian/Ubuntu) `loadkeys fr` will give you a French layout, `loadkeys be-latin1` will give you a Belgian layout, etc. There are several variations with additional non-ascii characters.

If you're working in an X environment, you need to use XKB or `xmodmap` or a GUI tool. `xmodmap` is the simplest of the two; the keymaps are in `/usr/share/xmodmap` (on Debian/Ubuntu, I haven't checked that they're in the same place on BackTrack). For example `xmodmap /usr/share/xmodmap/xmodmap.fr` will give you a French layout.

An alternative is to log into the machine via ssh. Then you would have your favorite keymap anyway. (Of course you'd have to type something in the machine first to enable an ssh daemon.)